# How can I tell what dynamic modules (not compiled-in) are active and working for nginx?

Tags: nginx, centos

When I do `nginx -V` it only shows me those modules that were compiled in... I want to confirm that my `load_module` directives in `nginx.conf` are actually working.

Comment: Typically you don't load modules for the fun of it, you need to load them to be able to use the functionality they provide. If  they were not loaded I would expect to seen an error similar to "`unknown directive "some_directive_provided_by_missing_module"`" when you define and use that  directive in your config...

Comment: Right, thanks. Ok. I have some modules that are NOT throwing an error and at the same time, don't appear (?) to be loading. That's why I want to get confirmation about what is-- or is not-- happening.

Comment: How have you determined that the modules don't appear to be loading?